# Getting hold of XML element using combobox

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have xml that has consists out of category elements and each category has its own elements, e.g. If cars is the category, cars will have elements like make, model, speed and if books is the category, books will have elements like author, chapters ext.

I have a combo box in which I list all the categories. Once a category is selected, I want to store the attributes/elements of that category into a variable. I debugged and this is not happening.

I am a new C# developer and hope someone can have a look at a code snippet and maybe point me into a direction as to what I am doing wrong.

```
private void cmbBoxCatagory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   String selectedCatagory = cmbBoxCatagory.Text;
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("a location");
    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xelement.Elements();
      var category =
      from c in elements
      where (string)c.Element("categoryName").Value == selectedCatagory
      select c;
    IEnumerable<XElement> dataItems = category.Elements();
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help you unless you also show a sample of the XML. Also, what *is* happening? What is the value of `dataItems`?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cmbBoxCatagory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   var selectedCatagory = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("a location");
    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xelement.Elements();
      var category =
      from c in elements
      where (string)c.Element("categoryName").Value == (string)selectedCatagory.Value
      select c;
    IEnumerable<XElement> dataItems = category.Elements();
}
```

Comment: Adding some context to this would make it a better answer.